# JLabel isn't recognized properly in ActionListener

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, scope, jlabel

I'm asking this as a very last resort as I have not been able to find any help concerning the issue I'm having with this Random Number Game.

The issue is that when I try to run the program, there is an error in the ActionListener that says that "guessResult cannot be resolved".

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class Project8 extends JFrame
{
private JTextField numGuessFld;
private JButton guessBtn, guessAgainBtn, playAgainBtn;
private int randNum;
private Container c = getContentPane();
private int numGuessed;
private Random rn = new Random();



public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Project8 frm = new Project8();
    frm.setSize(400,150);
    frm.setVisible(true);
    frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);     
}//end main

public Project8()
{
    c.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    setTitle("Number Guessing Game");

    JLabel gameDescriptLbl = new JLabel("I have a number between 1 and 1000.  Can you guess my number?");
    c.add(gameDescriptLbl);

    JLabel numGuessLbl = new JLabel("Please enter your first guess. ");
    c.add(numGuessLbl);

    numGuessFld = new JTextField(4);
    c.add(numGuessFld);

    guessBtn = new JButton("Guess");
    c.add(guessBtn);

    guessAgainBtn = new JButton("Guess Again");
    guessAgainBtn.setEnabled(false);
    c.add(guessAgainBtn);

    playAgainBtn = new JButton("Play Again?");
    playAgainBtn.setEnabled(false);
    c.add(playAgainBtn);

    JLabel guessResult = new JLabel("");
    c.add(guessResult);

    Handler handler = new Handler();

    numGuessFld.addActionListener(handler);
    guessBtn.addActionListener(handler);
    guessAgainBtn.addActionListener(handler);
    playAgainBtn.addActionListener(handler);

    randNum = rn.nextInt(1000)+1;
}//end constructor Project8

private class Handler implements ActionListener
{       
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {           
        if (e.getSource() == guessBtn)
        {               
            String input = numGuessFld.getText();
            numGuessed = Integer.parseInt(input);
            System.out.println(numGuessed);
            System.out.println(randNum);                

            if (numGuessed < randNum)
            {
                c.setBackground(Color.blue);                    
                guessResult.setText("Too low!");
                guessAgainBtn.setEnabled(true);                     
            }
            else if (numGuessed > randNum)
            {
                c.setBackground(Color.red);
                guessResult.setText("Too high!");                   
                guessAgainBtn.setEnabled(true);                 
            }
            else if (numGuessed == randNum)
            {
                c.setBackground(Color.yellow);
                guessResult.setText("Correct!");                    
                guessAgainBtn.setEnabled(false);
                guessBtn.setEnabled(false);
                numGuessFld.setBackground(Color.green);
                numGuessFld.setEditable(false);
                playAgainBtn.setEnabled(true);                  
            }   

        }//end guessBtn if          

        if (e.getSource() == guessAgainBtn)
        {
            numGuessFld.setText("");

        }//end guessAgainBtn if

        if (e.getSource() == playAgainBtn)
        {
            c.setBackground(null);
            numGuessFld.setText("");                
            guessAgainBtn.setEnabled(false);
            guessBtn.setEnabled(true);
            numGuessFld.setBackground(null);
            numGuessFld.setEditable(true);
            playAgainBtn.setEnabled(false); 
            randNum = rn.nextInt(1000)+1;
        }//end playAgainBtn if          
    }//end ActionPerformed
}//end Handler
}//end Project8
```

any help would be greatly appreciated...especially if it arrives before 4:30 :) Thank you!

Comment: Seems like you are using some simple text editor. If you use an IDE like Eclipse, Netbeans, or IntelliJ IDEA, etc they can help you a lot, because they are able to highlight such mistakes in your code before you run it and provide some useful tips.

Comment: @hage I'm using eclipse, that's where I was running into the problem even before I ran it. Thanks for the suggestion though! My "prof" (not a very good prof imho) makes us use JGrasp in-class but I have eclipse as a portable app on my flash drive, so I code in that and copy-paste into JGrasp for his sake.

Comment: _especially if it arrives before 4:30_ - haha, homework deadline in which timezone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a scoping issue. Try making `guessResult` a *member variable*, not a *local variable*.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response! worked like a charm! (I'll accept the answer when it allows me to) This gave me so much trouble for such an easy fix...Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

`guessResult` is defined only in your constructor, so therefore not visible by any other methods. You should make it a member of your class if you want it to be accessible elsewhere.